# CountIfs with variable range

Tags: excel, vba

Try to do a `CountIfs` on a range that changes column through each iteration - using a fixed column through `Range("A:A")` works, but converting it to numbers or variables fails.

I have tried to adjust this a few different ways - when I convert it to a fixed `column ("A:A")` it works, but anything else causes it to fail.

**Works:**

```
MRank=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Performance").Range("F:F"), Location, Sheets("Performance").Range("G:G"), ">=" & MValue)
```

**Does not work:**

```
MRank=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Performance").Range("F:F"), Location, Sheets("Performance").Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(1987, 7)), ">=" & MValue)
```

**Does not work:**

```
MRank=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Performance").Range("F:F"), Location, Sheets("Performance").Range(Cells(3, SelectedColumn), Cells(LastRow, SelectedColumn)), ">=" & MValue)
```

Should return a count of locations in the same area that have a metric value = to or higher than the selected value.

Comment: Such formulas like 'COUNTIF' parameters expect ranges of the same size to work.

Comment: Another thing. I think that you should declare your worksheet: `Dim ws as Worksheet` set the variable`Set ws = `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Performance")` and then in your line of code use `ws.Range(ws.Cells(), ws.Cells())` instead of `Range(Cells(), Cells())`. Otherwise the `Cells()` will be referenced to the `ActiveSheet` instead of the one you want

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos So if I use the code above, I'd also have to do a Sheets("Performance"). before each cell reference?

Comment: Yeah obviously. Or you could do `With Workbook.Worksheet("wsName")` place the code here and use `.Cells` instead of `Cells` and then `End With`. Every time you do not reference something it will either be referenced to the active object by default or not work at all

Answer (score 0):

This will be incorporate Danny & JVDV's comments to the post.

---

In your working formula, the whole columns are used, whcih inherently makes thigns take longer to calculate/filldown/etc.  Working with exact, uniform ranges is fairly ideal, wherever possible.

Stealing your working code to build off of:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Performance").Range("F:F"), Location, Sheets("Performance").Range("G:G"), ">=" & MValue)
```

Breaking that down, I would input some variables to set for ranges:

```
Application.CountIfs(LocRng, Location, MValRng, ">=" & MValue)
```

Use variables to help define the ranges, such that:

```
sr = 3 'from example, starting row
lr = 1987 'from example, last row
With ws 'Danny's suggestion to post
    set LocRng = .cells(sr,"F").Offset(lr-sr)
    set MValRng = .cells(sr,"G").Offset(lr-sr)
End with
MRank = Application.CountIfs(LocRng, Location, MValRng, ">=" & MValue)
```

As you didn't show what `MValue` and `Location` were, I assume you have those defined elsewhere and they are working as intended.